# CMake disable all options for a library

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I'm a newbie with cmake and I have a SDL source code directory which I'd like to use in my project. I copied the entire source directory into my project and wrote

```
add_subdirectory(SDL2-2.0.3)
```

into my CMakeLists.txt file. Now the problem is: SDL comes with a lot of options enabled by default:

```
set_option(VIDEO_COCOA         "Use Cocoa video driver" ${APPLE})
set_option(DIRECTX             "Use DirectX for Windows audio/video" ${WINDOWS})
...
```

and I don't want all of them, just two or three modules that I'm going to use. How can I disable ALL of them at once and just enable the two/three I need?

I tried with

```
option(DIRECTX "Use DirectX for Windows audio/video" OFF)
```

but I don't like having to repeat all the options I don't want in the file, it would be easier to just default all the options to OFF and enable the ones I need. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is no command that does this.

The `option` command simply adds a variable with the given name and default value to the CMakeCache. Like the `set` command, it will not overwrite an existing value in the cache, even if that value is different from the default value specified for the option.

The idiomatic way to set options for an external library is indeed to manually [`set`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html) all the variables in the cache before invoking the third-party CMake script. I would advise you to do it like this.

The problem with what you are trying to do is that setting the options has to happen *before* the call to `add_subdirectory`, but detecting which options have been set by that script is only possible *after* that call. In theory you could enumerate all the cached variables set by SDL's CMake script by using the [`get_cmake_property`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/get_cmake_property.html) command and then reset them to `FALSE` after the `add_subdirectory` call. But then you would have to re-run CMake a second time for those changes to become active.

I'd strongly advise against using such hacks. It's very easy to accidentally mess up options when upgrading SDL in the future and it's not nice having to explain to your users that they have to run CMake twice for building to succeed.